# Affectiva mscorlib.dll and dependencies error

Tags: c#, dll, mscorlib, affdex-sdk

I'm building a C# Affectiva product, up until a few days ago everything was working fine. I did a clean install of Windows 10 and I am using Visual Studio Enterprise. I keep having the following error stating missing mscorlib.dll or affect.dll

[Affectiva Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LFLs.jpg)

I've tried referencing the dll, recopying the proper dll for debug mode, ensured .net Framework 4.0 is loaded and the VS C++ Redist 2013. I've ensured all updates are complete on my PC. I'm the only one in the group that can't run the program now. I don't know what else to do.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a simple file-not-found error. Enable loader snaps with unmanaged debugging enabled or use SysInternals' Process Monitor to find out what file it is looking for.  If that doesn't get you anywhere then contact the owner for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a program named Dependency Walker. Ran it, and the files it says I was missing was from the Windows 8.1 API set. I install those and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing affdex-native.dll in your build directory. You might have that in place the previous time, but since you updated Windows and did a clean build the dll went missing from your build directory.Here is the place where it is added in the [csproj](https://github.com/Affectiva/affdexme-win/blob/master/AffdexMe.csproj#L197) file for AffdexMe.